# Graphql returns null id for mongoose aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, aggregation-framework, apollo-server

Graphql returns null id for mongoose aggregation query, but works ok other mongoose queries.

Here is my mongoose schema:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const ObjectId = Schema.Types.ObjectId;

const productSchema = new Schema({
  _id: ObjectId,
  price: Number
})

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema, 'Product')
```

Here is my Graphql schema:

```
type Product {
    id: ID
    price: String
}
```

Graphql normal query:

```
   context.Product.findOne()
```

Result with console.log:

```
[ {
    price: 10,    
    _id: 5d7f8efebff791dcd3bb1b69
}]
```

Result with graphql:

```
 "getSearch": [
      {
        "id": "5d7f8efebff791dcd3bb1b69",
        "price": 10,
  }]
```

Everything is fine here. 
**Now the problem is with aggregation query:**

GraphQL query:

```
context.Product.aggregate(
          [
            { $sample: { size: 1 } }
          ]
    )
```

Result with console.log:

```
[ { _id: 5d7f8f23bff791dcd3bb1da3,
    price: 5
}]
```

Result with GraphQL:

```
 "test": [
          {
            "id": null",
            "price": 7,
      }]
```

The problem here is:

- the id is null
- the responses from console.log and graphql are different objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documents in MongoDB normally don't have an `id` property, just an `_id` property. This is shown in the console output you're seeing. However, mongoose model instances do have a getter for `id` that returns the value of `id`. [From the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id):

> Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an id virtual getter by default which returns the documents _id field cast to a string, or in the case of ObjectIds, its hexString.

What's returned by methods like `find` and `findOne` are instances of the [Model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html) that have this getter. However, using `aggregate` results in plain JavaScript objects being returned instead (with no getter).

You can write a resolver for the `id` field to pull the value from either `id` or `_id`:

```
function resolve (parent, args, context, info) {
  return parent.id || parent._id
}
```

Comment: There's no reason this would somehow interfere with Apollo Client's cacheRedirects. If it does, then it's an issue with how you're implementing cacheRedirects.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `id` element to the result works fine to mine

```
   const res = await Product.aggregate(
          [
            { $sample: { size: 1 } }
          ]
    )
    res.forEach(element => {
         element.id = element._id 
    });
    return res;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add both IDs if you don't want to change every single instance of it.

```js
type Product {
  id: ID
  _id: ID
  price: String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongoose with `nest js` and `GraphQL`, I have fixed it by changing the `id` to `_id` and removing the `@prop` above it [Example on github](https://github.com/malek-laatiri/nestJs-GraphQL-MongoDB-example)

```
  @Prop()//remove this
  @Field(() => ID,{ nullable: true })
  _id: string;
```