# How to return id with Mongoose Aggregate Lookup with Apollo GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have an aggregate function that returns people in a collection:

```js
const getById = ({ id }) => {
    return Project.aggregate([
      { $match: { _id: Types.ObjectId(id) } },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "members",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "project_id",
          as: "members"
        }
      },
    ])
      .then(data => {
        const [project] = data;
        console.log(project) // see below
        return {
          id: project._id,
          ...project
        };
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

If I return the data from this I get the following:

```
// Server response
{ _id: 5e2f57b577a8ce59c79e74af,
  title: 'ok',
  user_id: 5e2dc7961e6b840c315b5a03,
  __v: 0,
  members:
   [ { _id: 5e447683b4f732cc9c4a9531,
       name: 'Karl Taylor',
       email: 'karl@queuey.dev',
       project_id: 5e2f57b577a8ce59c79e74af,
       position: 1,
       __v: 0 },
     { _id: 5e45be128ed96a5eaef5d13e,
       name: 'John Smith',
       email: 'john@queuey.dev',
       project_id: 5e2f57b577a8ce59c79e74af,
       position: 2,
       __v: 0 } ] }
```

However, when I query from the frontend using Apollo GraphQL, the id is null. (But it works on other items, as `id` is a getter for `id` but this does not happen on aggregate functions).

What is the best practice to map the `id` to the correct value? I would normally just use `array.map` but I feel like that might be overkill if I have too many members (at which point I would probably break this out to do pagination, but that's a different story.)

This is the response from frontend

```
// Client response
"project": {
      "id": "5e2f57b577a8ce59c79e74af",
      "title": "ok",
      "members": [
        {
          "id": null, // <-- Notice here is null
          "name": "Karl Taylor",
          "email": "karl@queuey.dev",
          "__typename": "Member"
        },
        {
          "id": null, // <-- Notice here is null
          "name": "John Smith",
          "email": "john@queuey.dev",
          "__typename": "Member"
        }
      ],
      "__typename": "Project"
    }
```

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166982/graphql-returns-null-id-for-mongoose-aggregation-query) is similar, however, I do not believe it is a duplicate because we are querying different data. (the answer does not solve my question.)

I need to be able to return `id` otherwise cached redirects will not work.

Comment: Your field is named `id` but MongoDB returns an `_id`.

Comment: Duplicate of [Graphql returns null id for mongoose aggregation query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166982/graphql-returns-null-id-for-mongoose-aggregation-query)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I've actually commented on that question previously. But it does not answer my issue. I am not having issues with a resolver. I am having issues with nested data which I need solving. Thanks

Comment: The issue is your lack of a resolver. If your data source returns `foo` and your field is named `bar`, you need to tell GraphQL to use the value of `foo` when resolving `bar`. Mongoose [has a virtual getter for id](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id) that uses the value of `_id` so you may not always hit this issue. But when you use aggregate, the returned objects are [not instances of your model classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038855/mongoose-virtuals-in-mongodb-aggregate), so there's no getter.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well when I try to use aggregations.
simply you can you both ID's(`id` and `_id`) but it's not good thing.

what I use is to iterate the data

if the returning data of the query is not array use this

```
return {
    ...res._doc,
    id: res._id,
}
```

but the returning data is an array you can add `id` to the response variable like below using `forEach`

```
res.forEach(element => {
     element.id = element._id 
});
return res;
```